# Magento 2 in admin grid display order table data

Tags: magento2.3, grid, order-grid

Magento 2 in admin grid display order table data. How to display this?

can you give me any suggestions please?

Comment: You mean you have to create the UI grid ?

Comment: yes I create a custom module I want to display sales_order table in admin grid

Comment: in which methods you use to create admin UI grid( UI component or block method)

Comment: using the Block method